# How to calculate a row vector with function of matrix as input variable?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a simple row vector `c` with stepsize 0.5, from 10 to 100.(1x181)
Now I would like to get new row vector `f` which is equal to :

```
f = c(i) * (c(i)+5) + 1/c(i) + 2^c(i)
```

`c(i)` is the elements of `c`.

How can I implement this equation in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab handles matrix operations like a peace of cake!

```
c = 10:0.5:100
f = (c.*(c+5))+ (1./c) + (2.^c)
```

Answer (score 0):

can be done with a simple for loop

```
f = zeros(length(c),1);
for i = 1:length(c)
    f(i) = c(i)*(c(i)+5) +1/(c(i)) + 2^(c(i));
end
```